# Check if input in textbox is email

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to validate if the userinput is an email adress (adding a member to database).

The user will enter data in TextBox, when the validating event gets called; I want to check if the input is a valid email adress. So consisting of atleast an @ and a dot(.) in the string.

Is there any way to do this through code, or perhaps with a Mask from the MaskedTextbox?

Comment: look up a Regex for validation emails, you should be easily able to find those

Comment: possible duplicate of [email validation in a c# winforms application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1199413/email-validation-in-a-c-sharp-winforms-application)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Don't bother with Regex. [It's a Bad Idea.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/using-a-regular-expression-to-validate-an-email-address)

I normally *never* use exceptions to control flow in the program, but personally, in this instance, I prefer to let the experts who created the `MailAddress` class do the work for me:

```
try
{
    var test = new MailAddress("");
}
catch (FormatException ex)
{
    // wrong format for email
}
```

Comment: +1 for mentioning the `MailAddress` class.  I had completely forgotten about it.

Comment: Holy hell that `Regex` is a mess... lol.  I am thinking I may have to delete my answer to this question since I _suggested_ using a `Regex` in the first place.

Comment: I don't know why but this method doesn't work when you enter a mail like this : mail@mail --> this mail is valid using this way but invalid because it doesn't contain a domain.

Answer (score 4):

Do not use a regular expression, it misses so many cases it's not even funny, and besides smarter people that us have come before to solve this problem.

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

public class TestModel{
    [EmailAddress]
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: This should be the top answer. It builds email validation right into the form, rendered with @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Email)

Answer (score 2):

Regex for simple email match:

```
@"\b[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}\b"
```

Regex for RFC 2822 standard email match:

```
@"[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?"
```

Answer (score 1):

See: How to: [Verify that Strings Are in Valid Email Format - MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/01escwtf%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

The Regex you are looking should be:

```
"^(?("")(""[^""]+?""@)|(([0-9a-z]((\.(?!\.))|[-!#\$%&'\*\+/=\?\^`\{\}\|~\w])*)(?<=[0-9a-z])@)) 
(?(\[)(\[(\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}\])|(([0-9a-z][-\w]*[0-9a-z]*\.)+[a-z0-9]{2,24}))$"
```

(From the same [source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/01escwtf%28v=vs.110%29.aspx))

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you use this way and it's working well for me.

```
    Regex reg = new Regex(@"\w+([-+.]\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*");
    if (!reg.IsMatch(txtEmail.Text))
    {
        // Email is not valid
    }
```

Comment: Please provide enough details for answering the question... The OP mentioned that the data comes from a `TextBox`, the validation event is called and it should match a string with `atleast an @ and a dot(.)`. How does your code fulfill these requirements and where are your `isValid` and `UserMessage` variables used in order to accomplish the OP's goal?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you use a [Regular Expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) like:

```
@"[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?"
```

To validate the input of your textbox.

Example code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   Regex emailRegex = new Regex(@"[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?
                                ^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+
                                [a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?");

   if (emailRegex.IsMatch(textBox1.Text))
   {
      MessageBox.Show(textBox1.Text + "matches the expected format.", "Attention"); 
   }
}
```

Edit:  I found a better, more comprehensive `Regex`.